# How do I get the latest software version without worrying about dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, software-installation

So I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and glabels 2.2.8.  The only problem is that glabels 3.0+ have been available for a loooooong time now.  I want to install glabels 3.0 just by downloading the deb and installing it (like every other windows computer gets to do by the way), but No, I don't have all the right dependecies installed.

So I start downloading all of those and installing them one by one.  Then I learn that those dependencies have dependencies and so on.  How on earth can I just download the latest software version with everything included in one installer package and install it?

I just want the latest and greatest version of the software that I like to use.I waited forever for Ubuntu to get the latest version of Miro added to the repository.

Comment: If you want latest software of all and ever, maybe ubuntu is not the distro for you to begin with. There are plenty or rolling and quasi rolling release distros.

Comment: You are using 12.04, which is advertised as a more-stable, long-term support version that does not regularly change software versions. If you want the latest software you should use the 6-monthly releases, which indeed (since 12.10) do have glabels 3. (See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=glabels )

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should stick to the stable official repositories, but seeing as you don't want that, read on.

There are several options when you want the latest version of a package or program, in order of preference:

### 1. Using a **[PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)**: This is the most preferred method.

#### Pros:

- You'll get the latest version of the software.
- The software will automatically update (with the *Software Updater*)
- Dependencies are automatically resolved (via `apt-get`)

#### Cons:

- It may take some time for a new version to be pushed to the PPA. This should be a lot faster than the normal repos, but keep it in mind.
- You're relying in the PPA maintainer to update it to the lates version. If (s)he chooses to abandon it, you'll be left with an old version. If it is an official PPA from a project, you should be fine, though.
- PPA Security: You're allowing a random person from the internet root access to your computer (during install).  See [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo), generally you should be fine but just a warning.

### 2. Using a provided Debian Package (.deb file)

#### Pros:

- You'll get the latest version of the software.
- Dependencies should be relatively easy to install with `apt-get`.

#### Cons:

- No automatic updating via the *Software Updater*. The program itself *might* provide auto-updating.
- Root access to your computer. The main points in [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo) still apply.

### 3. Using provided binaries

Note: This differs from "compiling from source", though they may be using the same archive formats.

#### Pros:

- You'll get the latest version of the software.

#### Cons:

- Dependencies may be more difficult to install.
- Installation is more difficult, files may need to be copied or moved manually.
- See Cons for Debian Package.

### 4. Compiling from source

#### Pros:

- You'll get the latest version of the software.

#### Cons:

- Compiling from source is often tricky and involves work with dependencies and such.
- See Cons for Using provided binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing via apt (advanced packaging tool) or Synaptic (GUI for apt). Apt will automatically resolve complex package dependencies for you. An apt-cache search glabels returns the following:

glabels - label, business card and media cover creation program for GNOME
...

So... sudo apt-get install glabels and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, forget LTS and install a Normal release instead. The package you want has [been in 3.0 since long ago.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=glabels) That way you don't have to worry about dependencies, etc.